# Need to kill all Workflows on a list in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: powershell, designer-workflow

Can someone explain to me how to do this using Powershell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#Site URL
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://urlforsite.com";
$web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true;    

#List Name
$list = $web.Lists["ListName"];

# Iterate through all Items in List and all Workflows on Items.         
foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
foreach ($wf in $item.Workflows) {

#Cancel Workflows        
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager]::CancelWorkflow($wf);      
}
}
$web.Dispose();
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595256/cancel-multiple-sharepoint-workflows-using-powershell